# Sharepoint Online: Search showing old and new names of renamed folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I have a customer with a Sharepoint Online site.
They have a Shared Document folder they use for sharing files.

When we first did migrate them to Sharepoint Online we moved all files from the old server to a folder called "Z-Drive". We then later renamed the folder to be called "Faelles".

The issue is that now, a month later, (The issue have been there all time, but we have now got to know about it) when we search, we get like a double search result back from what it does find of folders. So lets say we have a folder called "Design" it shows up 2 times, like this, when we search for Design:

Design (Link-to-sharepointonline\Z-Drive\Design) (The old one, that gives a 404 error)

Design (Link-to-sharepointonline\Faelles\Design) (The new one)

This is getting messy as when a user is selecting the wrong one, they get a error 404 when they select a search result with the old name.

We did a Reindex yesterday, but dosent seem to have done anything, but I am not sure how I can check the reindex status, to see if it is done.

Answer (score 1):

After re-indexing the SharePoint Online library, wait 24 hours for crawling, then search again. If this issue still exists, it is the time to contact the Online Support.